# Excel vba Autofill only empty cells

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have a column A with data up to A300.

In this range, some of theses cells are empty, some contain values.

In VBA, I set the formula of the cell A1 then I use the autofill function to set it all over my column (up to A300) like this :

```
ws.Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(300, 1))
```

My problem is that datas contain on some cells are erased too ! I'm trying to autofill like it but only throught the empties cells.

I tried to add a filter on my worksheet like this :

```
ws.Range("$A$1:$A$300").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
```

Then I reused the autofill function, but it seems to fill thourght the filtered cells...

Can't we add a parameter like "only empties cells" to the autofill function ? Something like this :

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(300, 1)), Criteria1:="="
```

Thanks for your replies !

Comment: What are you trying to fill them with? Static or progressive values? See the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with **xlCellTypeBlanks**.

Comment: I have an other problem with the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)". It results that If copy then paste an empty cell, these cell is no longer considered as a blank cell, and it isn't selected by this code (but this cell still empty) it's an already knew issue of the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). So I can get the error "No cell match" even if I have a blank cell. Do you know any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I miss-understood you question - Want to fill all blank cells with the value in A1? - here you go:

```
Sub Replace()

If Trim(Range("A1").Value) = "" Then
    MsgBox "There's no value in A1 to copy so there's nothing to copy to all blank cells", vbInformation, "Nothing in A1"
    Exit Sub
    Else
        Range("A1:A300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
        Selection.Value = Range("A1").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it's the easier answer !

Comment: I have an other problem with the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)". It results that If copy then paste an empty cell, these cell is no longer considered as a blank cell, and it isn't selected by this code (but this cell still empty) it's an already knew issue of the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). So I can get the error "No cell match" even if I have a blank cell. Do you know any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is here.. the first line finds all empty cells and selects them, the second enters the value in A1 into the selected cells so there can't be.. unless you have cells with a space in them (" ") which isn't considered blank - is that what's happening?

Comment: the formula I use put a value on the cell, or put "". So the first time, my cell is empty, then the formula put "" on it. The second I run my macro result by the error. Basically, VBA considers that a cell with "" isn't blanks. The blanks cells are the cells which wasn't get initialized. Put "" to a cell initialize it. The specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks) doesn't considers the initiliazed empty cell as a blank cell, so it results as an error...

Comment: If you are able to understand french, this topic clairly explain the problem : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d526009/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/cells-1-1-textbox1-vide-place-quoi-cellule-convaincu/

Comment: I can't understand French but I think I know the issue - I've edited the code above to handle if A1 = ""

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the problem. A1 would never be empty because I set the formula of A1 then I try to copy it to others blanks cells. Imagine I set a formula like it "=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,"OK","") and autofill that to all my column. It'll write "OK" every 2 rows. Now, I copy then specialPaste to keep only the formula result as brut data. Now If you do "Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)" you'll get the same error as me, because even if the cells are "empty" they already got initialized by the formula and the copy paste which set "" to theses cells...

Comment: Don't worry I'll finally use a loop. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

with data like:

[image]

I would do a single copy rather than a fill-down:

```
Sub luxation()
    Range("A1").Formula = "=ROW()"
    Dim rDest As Range
    Set rDest = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A1:A300").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))

    Range("A1").Copy rDest
End Sub
```

with this result:

[image]

*NOTE:*

The formulas adjust after being copied.

**EDIT#1:**

Please note that there are some circumstances under which this code will not work.  It is possible that `UsedRange` my not extend down to cell **A300**.

For example, if the worksheet is totally empty except for a formula in **A1** and some value in **A3**.  In this case `Rdest` will only include the single cell **A2**.  The code will leave **A4** through **A300** untouched.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's what i needed. For the "usedRange" I already got an issue with it. It seems to doesn't recalculate when you delete some data or other, but I can this without using the usedrange. Thanks again !

Comment: I have an other problem with the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)". It results that If copy then paste an empty cell, these cell is no longer considered as a blank cell, and it isn't selected by this code (but this cell still empty) it's an already knew issue of the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). So I can get the error "No cell match" even if I have a blank cell. Do you know any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want static values, I would use a loop.  The one below will fill all empty cells with poop:

```
Sub AllFillerNoKiller()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each c In ws.Range("A1:A300")
    If c.Value = "" Then c.Value = "poop"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works for the A1:A300 range, but I used is as an example, my real workbook would have more than 10k row and I would to avoid loop. But thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code:

```
stAddress = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
Sheet1.Range(st).Value = "Empty"
```

Comment: Thanks this code works too, even if it is more complex than the Jeremy's answer. Thanks btw !

Comment: I have an other problem with the "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)". It results that If copy then paste an empty cell, these cell is no longer considered as a blank cell, and it isn't selected by this code (but this cell still empty) it's an already knew issue of the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). So I can get the error "No cell match" even if I have a blank cell. Do you know any solution for this problem ?